# issue at javascript attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
var sr = 'http://www.example.com/example.js?rnd='+randomnumber;
document.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"" + sr + "\"  id-value-test=\"100\" >    </script>");
</script>
```

getting  unterminated string literal at **id-value-test**.Any idea?

Comment: There are better way os doing this - nevertheless, the easiest is to use nested quotes with alternatiing `"` and `'` - `document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='" + sr + "'"  id-value-test='100'>    </script>");`

Comment: @karthikr: True, but nested quotes aren't the problem here. :-)

Answer (score 8):

When doing the HTML parsing, browsers don't parse JavaScript, and so they stop at the first `</script>` sequence they find — even if it's in a string literal, or a JavaScript comment.

To avoid it, just do anything to interrupt the `</script>` in your string, such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
var sr = 'http://www.example.com/example.js?rnd='+randomnumber;
document.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"" + sr + "\"  id-value-test=\"100\" >    <\/script>");
<!-- Change is here -----------------------------------------------------------------------------^  -->
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
var sr = 'http://www.example.com/example.js?rnd='+randomnumber;
document.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"" + sr + "\"  id-value-test=\"100\" >    </" + "script>");
<!-- Change is here ----------------------------------------------------------------------------^  -->
</script>
```